# Block/disable all background elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have fixed positioned div which must be on the top of the page when opened.And it must stretch all over the page.

I have some inputs as a background elements on body.

I want to block/disable and prevent all the keyboard/click events from background elements(inputs).

Here is the code:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KyGzmN

```
<body style="
    margin: 0;
">

<div style="
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: black;
    z-index: 9999;
    position: fixed;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
">
 <div style="
    height: 100px;
    width: 200px;
    background: yellow;
    margin-top: 100px;
    margin-left: 100px;
">My Content In Fixed Div
</div>

</div>


  <input>
  <input>
  <input>

</body>
```

I can prevent mouse click events but when I press tab it focus the inputs.I don't want that.

I totally disable/block the background elements.How can I do that with css?

I can't use jquery.Maybe pure javascript.But I need that with css.

Comment: `Here is the code` -No, add it as a **working snippet** here. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Add `tabindex="-1"` to every input?

Comment: I can't.There can be lots of elements as a background elements.Like hundreds.

Answer (score 0):

Add `disabled="disabled"` to your inputs, statically or using js if it has to change :

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('yourClass');

function disable() {
    [].forEach.call(inputs , function(input) {
    input.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
    });
}

function enable() {
  [].forEach.call(inputs , function(input) {
    input.removeAttribute('disabled');
  });
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/axn5wvye/8/